# React - Loading data before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react and I have a question about a best practice that sees me make a mistake .
I call an API to retrieve information and modify an array in the state once the response is returned by the API. In the "render" I have to retrieve the information from this array (when it is completed) or **it sends me back an error because the array is empty when the render is initialized.**

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0,
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`API_ADDRESS`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token XXX`,
        },
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          items: response.results,
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        notification.warning({
          message: error.code,
          description: error.message,
        })
      })
  }

  changeDialog = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      activeIndex: index,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { activeIndex, items } = this.state
    const {
      first_name: firstName,
      last_name: lastName,
      phone,
      email,
      address,
    } = items[activeIndex]
```

The error indicates :

> TypeError: _items$activeInde is undefined

**How can I solve this error related to data loading? (trying to keep the destrying elements method)**

Thanks a lot 
Eliott

Comment: I'd not say that this in any way specific to react. The problem is that you blindly try to destructure `items[activeIndex]` without ensuring that you don't get a null-reference exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- beware of `this` inside the `Promise` returned by axios. You use `function(){}` so the `this` inside is not the component's instance. Change it to an arrow function.
- add a guard so you won't destructure `undefined` when `activeIndex` points to an `item` element that is not there (which happens in the initial loading before the axios fetches the data).

Fix:

```js
// ... (code not shown remains unmodified)
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get(`API_ADDRESS`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Token XXX`,
      },
    })
    .then(response => {                                             // changed this line
      this.setState({
        items: response.results,
      })
    })
// ... (code not shown remains unmodified)

render() {
  const { activeIndex, items } = this.state
  if (!items[activeIndex]) {                                        // added this line
    return <div>Hold tight while items are being fetched...</div>;  // added this line
  }                                                                 // added this line
  const {
    first_name: firstName,
// ... (code not shown remains unmodified)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because API that you fetch from server is **async**. The first time render of Component, data that you **setState** in **axios** still not yet updated, it just updated when Component render the second time.

So you must check state in render Component like this to make sure that if `activeIndex is defined` then declare variable with `items[activeIndex]` :

```
activeIndex && const {
      first_name: firstName,
      last_name: lastName,
      phone,
      email,
      address,
} = items[activeIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your component like so:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0,
      items: [],
      isFetching: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // staring your fetching
    this.setState({isFetching: true});
    axios
      .get(`API_ADDRESS`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token XXX`,
        },
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        // finish fetching when your response is ready :)
        this.setState({
          items: response.results,
          isFetching: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // finish fetchnig
        this.setState({isFetching: false})
        notification.warning({
          message: error.code,
          description: error.message,
        })
      })
  }

  changeDialog = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      activeIndex: index,
    })
  }

  render() {

    // if your component is while fetching shows a loading to the user
    if(this.state.isFetching) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    // if there is no results shows a msg to the user
    if(this.state.items.length === 0) return <div>there is not items!!!</div>

    const { activeIndex, items } = this.state
    const {
      first_name: firstName,
      last_name: lastName,
      phone,
      email,
      address,
    } = items[activeIndex]
```